# How are files stored in memory and how can i use that knowledge in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

How are files stored in memory?
I suppose that when i write in a text file something like Hello World, the file in memory looks like this:
`01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111` 1 Byte 1 Char?

Well... I'm 90% sure I'm wrong about this and that's why I put this question.

The actual thing is that I really want to know how Images are stored into memory because I want to use this to edit images or create ASCII art, and i feel like i could do this without a 3rd party library.

The reason I didn't put my time into learning a library is that there are lots of them(I don't know which one to pick) and i don't know at what point I should looking into them... Well, this would be a different question

Comment: That's up to the image format.

Comment: (1) 1 byte per `char` is guaranteed by the C++ memory model. But note that a `char`, a C++ byte, can be more than 8 bits. The number of bits per byte is given by `CHAR_BIT` from the `<limits.h>` header. (2) The term "memory" refers by default to main memory, RAM. Files are seldom stored in memory, they're usually stored on disk. But it's possible to map a file to memory, or to use a RAM-disk.

Comment: Each image file format is different.  The simplest might be BMP and one of the more complicated JPEG.  Using a library is a good idea so you can spend more time working on your images than re-learning image file formats that someone else is an expert on and put their knowledge in the library.

Answer (score 2):

Files are *stored* on media such as disk, they are *represented* in memory. How data is stored on media will depend on the file content, in your case the type of image, such as jpeg, png, etc. You can look those up online and then write code which reads that data into whatever representation in memory is best for you.

Many formats are compressed and will require complex work to decode, so you may want to start by looking at [bmp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391(v=vs.85).aspx). However, even this is still "encoded" and if you can't work with the data represented that way, you'll need to choose your representation, e.g. a giant 2d array of RGB values, and write your own code to read the disk image into that representation.